# Работа с Telegram API

Tags: php, api, telegram

Можно ли как-то получить список подписчиков у публичных телеграм каналов? 
Всё что на данный момент нашел - [getchatmemberscount](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount), но там требуется chat_id, который я узнать никак не могу.
Есть какие-то другие способы, либо же остаётся только парсить?

Answer (score 1):

вместо чат id можно использовать просто имя канала